# SQL Insert multiple Values where 1 value comes from a select query

Tags: sql

I am searching for a solution to add multiple values into a table where one of these values is coming from another table. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Telnumber, adress) VALUES ('12324567890',
SELECT applicatieID from Applicatie WHERE Naam = 'piet' )
```

So 1 of the values has to come from another table and the other values I have to insert myself. The above query won't work. Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Telnumber, adress)
    SELECT '12324567890', applicatieID
    from Applicatie
    WHERE Naam = 'piet';
```

`insert . . . select` does almost everything that `insert . . . values` does, plus more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INSERT INTO with your SELECT request :

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Telnumber, adress) 
SELECT '1234567890', applicatieID 
FROM Applicatie 
WHERE Naam = 'piet'
```